# How can i access in server side AspxGridView row's combobox after click New Row button

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

I have an AspxGridView which has another aspxgridview in its detailrows. The second gridview has a combobox in its row. I want to set this combobox's selected value when I click New Row on the second gridview. So, how can i access that combobox after click new row button?

KR,

Çağın

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered your question at:

[How can i access in server side AspxGridView row's combobox after click New Row button](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=Q317024)